# DNS records: redundancy, and auxiliary servers

Tags: networking, security, dns, redirection, redundancy

I have a domain, this domain points to a front end server. I have two front end servers, one ddos protected intreppid, with 20 GB/ps, other protected with secured servers from 2 to 10 GB/ps. So a DDOS attack, 1 GB/ps strength will knock out my secured servers server. The secured servers server naturally has a 100% uptime. Where as the intreppid server has 95-97% uptime due to accidents in their data-center. Currently I only use secured servers server as the primary server and the intreppid server that I have been paying for 500 dollars a month for more then a month has never been used. What I want to do is to use my intreppid server as primary server, and if it is unpingable, ddosed, or offline, I want to use secured servers as auxiliary back up server.

I remember from my previous years there used to be a service somewhere that would use a different ip for your gaming server if the first server was down. This service cost 10 bucks a month. I don't remember where it is from. When researching this I get all kinds of goofy results like switching dns records to get change in 48 hours. I need something that will switch over in less then a minute in an emergency.

Thoughts? opinions? knowledge please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something to switch in less than 60 seconds, then you need either of the following:

- Both servers behind the same router, where the router is automatically pinging the primary server and switches the routing tables as soon as the primary goes down. This is generally not feasible in most datacenters unless you're buying a lot of rackspace. Talk to your salesrep.
- The DNS entry is configured with a TTL of less than 60 seconds, and a tool on the backup host which monitors the primary, and updates the DNS entry when it detects the primary is inaccessible (and restores it when the primary is accessible again). This will be somewhat unreliable because it's likely that some routers or DNS proxies will ignore a TTL so low (they are usually set at 8 hours or more, not 60 seconds), so some computers or even some whole regions (if the ISP dns is ignoring the low TTL) can wind up using the old IP until the DNS cache clears.

Comment: i am looking for like a website, an internet service that switches dns entries for you.

Answer (score 0):

Even though service recommendations are off-topic on SuperUser, I know two parties that provide this service:

- DynDNS in their managed DNS offering http://dyn.com/managed-dns/
- LiquiDNS https://www.liquidns.com/